# CSS problem with page footer

Tags: css

I have defined my page footer in the css file as:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #66CCCC;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
}
```

Now if more data gets added to the page, it moves below the footer, and the footer stays where it is. Any way to fix this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use absolute positioning for footers, tying them to the viewport (which is what `bottom: 0px` does).

If you want a footer at the bottom of the viewport, or the bottom of the content (whichever is longer), use [sticky footers](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 0):

Use position: fixed; for this.

Comment: This is the easiest way to fix it, but it's not supported in IE6, unfortunately...

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mozilla.org/causes/serviceweek/internethealth/ . Of course it is your right to disagree to what they write, but I also find IE quite disgusting and don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 definition for height? Another way is to set `min-height` so that its height can 'grow' with the content while not go less than certain height.

```
#footer {
  .....
  min-height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for purely CSS you could do the following:

HTML File:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Site.css" runat="server" rev="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Page">
        <div id="Header">
            This is my "Header Content"!
        </div>
        <div id="Content">
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
            This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...          This is my long content...
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            This is my "Footer Content"!
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (Site.css):

```
#Page
{
    background-color: Red;
}

#Header
{
    background-color: Purple;
    color: White;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: xx-large;    
    text-align: center;
}

#Content
{
    background-color: Lime;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background: #66CCCC;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

I of course set up the colors and positions in odd ways to show where the divs meet.  When you add content to the page, add it to the content area, and since we have the `overflow: auto;` for the content div, it will scroll and your header / footer will be static.

Hope this helps!